# How to check programmatically that wifi is connected or data pack is enabled but there is no internet connection?

Tags: android, android-wifi, gprs

I am using wifi and GPRS to connect the internet.but in some situations such as wifi connected but no internet connection and same with data (GPRS).data on but no net connections.

for wifi i am using below code.this returns true always

```
 public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info=null;
        if(context!=null){
            info= IsNetConnectionAvailable.getNetworkInfo(context);
        }
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }
```

and for mobile data i am using below code. it will give true or false based on data on off.

```
public boolean isMobileDataEnable() {
    boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) method.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Some problem accessible private API and do whatever error handling you want here
    }
    return mobileDataEnabled;
}
```

but how to catch the condition when there is no internet connection on both condition? is there any android api can help for above situations.
please help me to resolve this.

Comment: With a website I would do a simple XHR request to determine whether or not I can connect to the web, perhaps you could do the same?

Comment: @mic Yes i did that but that is time consuming.because i should check the net connection in every activity

Answer (score 4):

Method to get network type either it is mobile or wifi.

```
public static String getNetworkType(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return info.getTypeName();
}
```

Method to check whether phone is connected to INTERNET or not

```
public static boolean isInternetIsConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            return true;

        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use the below [library](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork) for more control over the network connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but my problem is different. ur method isInternetIsConnected() gives always true when connected to data or wifi. but my problem when there is low wifi or some data plan issue(data over) or signal fluctuations on both cases in those situations ur method gives true but actually there is no net connection. i want to catch those conditions and tell the user no net available.i am expecting android API help

Comment: Have you seen the library its has observe functionality in it.

Comment: Here one more link for checking network speed https://android.jlelse.eu/designing-android-apps-to-handle-slow-network-speed-dedc04119aac

Comment: ReactiveNetwork able to solve my problem but it making my app too much slow ..any alternate solution to use this library

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Facebook Connection Class](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class) to find the network speed and whether you are connected to the web or not. For every activity, you don't need to check just create one Application Class and implement the logic and through that class fetch the connection checker.

I have implemented this for Live Streaming, whether I have an active network connection with a specified range of bandwidth. I don't have a working code for your scenario. It might help.